# Can you join on a subquery with Doctrine 2 DQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

Is there a way to access a joined entity's relation in the `WITH` clause of a join? Im trying to avoid using an `IN` clause with a subquery.

**Edit:** Or is there a way to join on a subquery rather than using `IN`?

i.e. Making sure the joined object's `t.final` value is 1.

**Trying to Avoid This Query**

```
SELECT o
FROM Entity\Order o
WHERE o.status = :orderStatus
AND o.id NOT IN (
  SELECT o2.id
  FROM Entity\ServiceRequest s
  JOIN s.order o2
  JOIN s.serviceType t
  WHERE s.status = :serviceStatus
  AND t.final = 1
)
```

**Failing Rewrite Attempt:**
Not able to access `s.serviceType.final`

```
SELECT o
FROM Entity\Order o
LEFT JOIN o.serviceRequests s
    WITH s.status = :serviceStatus
    AND s.serviceType.final = 1
LEFT JOIN s.serviceType t
WHERE o.status = :orderStatus
AND COUNT(s) = 0
```

**Order Entity:**

```
<?php
namespace Entity;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\Order")
 * @Table(name="orders")
 */
class Order
{
  const STATUS_REVIEW    = 0;
  const STATUS_PENDING   = 1;
  const STATUS_SCHEDULED = 2;
  const STATUS_COMPLETE  = 3;

  /**
   * @Id
   * @Column(type="integer")
   * @GeneratedValue
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice")
   *
   * @var Invoice
   */
  protected $invoice;

  /**
   * @Column(type="integer")
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $status;

  /**
   * @Column(type="smallint", name="is_canceled")
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $isCanceled;

  /**
   * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ServiceRequest", mappedBy="order")
   *
   * @var ServiceRequest[]
   */
  protected $serviceRequests;

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  /**
   * @return \Entity\Invoice
   */
  public function getInvoice()
  {
    return $this->invoice;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   *
   * @uses \Entity\Order::STATUS_REVIEW
   * @uses \Entity\Order::STATUS_PENDING
   * @uses \Entity\Order::STATUS_SCHEDULED
   * @uses \Entity\Order::STATUS_COMPLETE
   */
  public function getStatus()
  {
    return $this->status;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $status
   *
   * @uses \Entity\Order::STATUS_REVIEW
   * @uses \Entity\Order::STATUS_PENDING
   * @uses \Entity\Order::STATUS_SCHEDULED
   * @uses \Entity\Order::STATUS_COMPLETE
   */
  public function setStatus($status)
  {
    $this->status = $status;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getIsCanceled()
  {
    return $this->isCanceled;
  }

  public function cancel()
  {
    $this->isCanceled = 1;
  }

  /**
   * @return ServiceRequest[]
   */
  public function getServices()
  {
    return $this->services;
  }
}
```

**ServiceRequest Entity:**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="order_service_requests")
 */
class ServiceRequest
{
  const STATUS_REVIEW    = 0;
  const STATUS_PENDING   = 1;
  const STATUS_SCHEDULED = 2;
  const STATUS_COMPLETE  = 3;

  /**
   * @Id
   * @Column(type="integer")
   * @GeneratedValue
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice")
   *
   * @var Invoice
   */
  protected $invoice;

  /**
   * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ServiceType")
   * @JoinColumn(name="service_types_id")
   *
   * @var ServiceType
   */
  protected $serviceType;

  /**
   * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order")
   * @JoinColumn(name="orders_id")
   *
   * @var Order
   */
  protected $order;

  /**
   * @Column(type="integer")
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $status;

  /**
   * @Column(type="smallint", name="is_canceled")
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $isCanceled;

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  /**
   * @return \Entity\Invoice
   */
  public function getInvoice()
  {
    return $this->invoice;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   *
   * @uses \Entity\ServiceRequest::STATUS_REVIEW
   * @uses \Entity\ServiceRequest::STATUS_PENDING
   * @uses \Entity\ServiceRequest::STATUS_SCHEDULED
   * @uses \Entity\ServiceRequest::STATUS_COMPLETE
   */
  public function getStatus()
  {
    return $this->status;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $status
   *
   * @uses \Entity\ServiceRequest::STATUS_REVIEW
   * @uses \Entity\ServiceRequest::STATUS_PENDING
   * @uses \Entity\ServiceRequest::STATUS_SCHEDULED
   * @uses \Entity\ServiceRequest::STATUS_COMPLETE
   */
  public function setStatus($status)
  {
    $this->status = $status;
  }

  /**
   * @return \Entity\ServiceType
   */
  public function getServiceType()
  {
    return $this->serviceType;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function isCanceled()
  {
    return $this->isCanceled;
  }

  public function getOrder()
  {
    return $this->order;
  }
}
```

**ServiceType Entity:**

```
<?php
namespace Entity;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="service_types")
 */
class ServiceType
{
  /**
   * @Id
   * @Column(type="integer")
   * @GeneratedValue
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @Column(type="smallint")
   *
   * @var int
   */
  protected $final;

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getFinal()
  {
    return $this->final;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're querying servicetype before it is joined.  Try:

```
SELECT o
FROM Entity\Order o
LEFT JOIN o.serviceRequests s
  WITH s.status = :serviceStatus
LEFT JOIN s.serviceType t
WHERE o.status = :orderStatus
AND COUNT(s) = 0
AND t.final = 1
```

Comment: Will that eliminate any orders that have a "final" service request? There are multiple service requests per order. I'm still a bit new to using DQL as opposed to normal SQL.

Comment: My apologies, based on your revised query, I had thought you wanted all finals.  If you want to eliminate all situations where t.final is 1 (boolean field?) then set t.final=0 in above query.