# Doctrine join WITH vs WHERE

Tags: join, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I'm joining multiple tables and I found two solution. I can't ready figure out what is the diference. Can anyone tell me?

Solution 1:

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("
    SELECT m FROM Model m
        JOIN m.battery b
        JOIN m.camera c
        JOIN m.connectivity co
        JOIN m.hardware h
        JOIN m.screen s
        JOIN m.sensor se                                                        
            WHERE b = m.battery
            AND c = m.camera
            AND co = m.connectivity
            AND h = m.hardware
            AND s = m.screen
            AND se = m.sensor"
);
```

Solution 2:

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("
    SELECT m FROM Model m
        JOIN m.battery b
        WITH m.battery = b
        JOIN m.camera c
        WITH m.camera = c
        JOIN m.connectivity co
        WITH m.connectivity = co
        JOIN m.hardware h
        WITH m.hardware = h
        JOIN m.screen s
        WITH m.screen = s
        JOIN m.sensor se
        WITH m.sensor = se
");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing `DQL` and you should not confuse it with `SQL`. In a `DQL` query join you don't need to add `id` fields explicitly to the join Doctrine takes care of it for you.

`"SELECT m FROM Model m JOIN m.battery b"` is sufficient.

to `fetch-join` add `b` to your select clause:

`"SELECT m, b FROM Model m JOIN m.battery b"`

If you want to join only batteries with a certain property, that is when you need to use the `WITH` clause in your `DQL`. For example join only batteries who's battery `status` is `empty`:

`"SELECT m, b FROM Model m JOIN m.battery b WITH b.status = 'empty'"`

Check [the documentation on DQL joins](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

From what i have read i can say:

When you use `Where` instead of `On` in join, there is one difference, `On` will apply before selection and `Where` will apply after the selection process by join.
 `WITH` is similar to `On` clause which lets you specify another condition in addition to `On`.
So I think when you use `With`, It will work like `ON` but `Where` will eliminate the result after selection by `Join`. 
It may helps: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422611/symfony2-querybuilder-join-on-and-with-difference):

Selected Answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596541/can-you-join-on-a-subquery-with-doctrine-2-dql) question also used two of them together with explanation.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof In inner join, yes but in outer join does not matter.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I think I was wrong. query optimizer will pick the best way for the join and they can use interchangeably. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause

Comment: @RobinDijkhof  The WHERE clause filters both the left and the right side of the JOIN, while the ON clause will always filter the right side only.

- If you always want to fetch the left side rows and only JOIN if some condition matches then you should the ON clause.
- If you want to filter both sides after the JOIN is made then you should use the WHERE clause.